# looping previously defined function

Tags: clojure, lisp

My goal is to iterate a function that I wrote, arbitrarily called gorilla, j times. Gorilla takes sequences as arguments. However, the code is riddled with errors (not on purpose), and returns key must be an integer.

Here is a copy of the code:

```
(defn gen-gorilla [seq j]
  (loop [level j gorilla seq]
    (if (= level 0)
      seq
      (if (> level 0)
        (recur (- level 1) (gorilla seq))))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of thing is what iterate is most useful for.

`(last (take 5 (iterate inc 0)))` => 4

so for this case you would want:

`(nth (iterate gorilla seq) j)`

Comment: You can use `(nth ...)` instead of `(last (take ...))`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you are binding the name `gorilla` in your loop, but this means calling `gorilla` refers to the latest sequence, not the function.

This can actually be quite nicely written with reduce

```
 (defn apply-gorilla [n s]
    (reduce (fn [s _] (gorilla s)) s (range n)))
```

This basically loops up to `n` and ignores `n` as it goes, simply repeatedly applying `gorilla` repeatedly.

If you really want explicit recursion

```
 (defn apply-gorilla [n s]
   (if (zero? n)
       s
       (recur (dec n) (gorilla s))))
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your use of `gorilla` in the `recur` call. `gorilla` in this case is a collection, defined in the `loop` statement, which, when you use them as functions is equivalent to indexing into them.

```
([1 2 3] 0) ;; => 1
```

But, you are passing a sequence as the index into the collection.

```
([1 2 3] [1 2 3]) ;; => Exception: Key must be integer
```

From your description, you are trying to call your function, `gorilla`, defined elsewhere. You would need to rename the var defined in the `loop` statement to something like the following:

```
(defn gen-gorilla [seq j]
  (loop [level j s seq]
    (if (= level 0)
      s
      (if (> level 0)
        (recur (- level 1) (gorilla s))))))
```